# Hello Firebase Experts recently i implemented firebase authentication using real time database, now i want to upload user profile image also how to?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[signup activity screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImBbj.jpg)

i implemented the rest of the picking image from the gallery and set it on image view! now I want the function to upload the user profile image along with signup details, please also mention is there any need of an extra variable in user model class? and what parameters, constructors, getters or setters i had to add after. the code of the user-model class is also given below, thanks in advance :)

// here is the function for registering the user:

```
        private void register_doctor () {
            String dname = et_name.getText().toString().trim();
            String demail = et_email.getText().toString().trim();
            String dpass = et_pass.getText().toString().trim();
            String dcpass = et_cnf_pass.getText().toString().trim();
            String dcontact = et_contact.getText().toString().trim();
            String dcity = et_city.getText().toString().trim();
            String dage = et_age.getText().toString().trim();


            if (dname.isEmpty()) {
                et_name.setError("Full Name is Required");
                et_name.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            if (demail.isEmpty()) {
                et_email.setError("Email is Required");
                et_email.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            if (dpass.isEmpty()) {
                et_pass.setError("Password is Required");
                et_pass.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            if (dpass.length() < 6) {
                et_pass.setError("Password Length Should be greater than 6 characters");
                et_pass.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            if (dcpass.isEmpty()) {
                et_cnf_pass.setError("Password is Required");
                et_cnf_pass.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            if (!dcpass.equals(dpass)) {
                et_cnf_pass.setError("Password Does not Matched!");
                et_cnf_pass.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            if (dcontact.isEmpty()) {
                et_contact.setError("Contact is Required");
                et_contact.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            if (dcity.isEmpty()) {
                et_city.setError("City is Required");
                et_city.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            if (dage.isEmpty()) {
                et_age.setError("Age is Required");
                et_age.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(demail, dpass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                User user = new User(dname, demail, dcontact, dcity, dage);
                                
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("doctors")
                                        .child("Doctors_Registration")
//                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .child(demail.replace(".", ","))
                                        .setValue(user)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Doctor Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Failed to Registered, Try Again!" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Failed to Registered, Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }




// here is my user-model class code
package com.example.iotbaseddriverhealthmonitoring;

public class User {
    public String name, email, password, contact, city, age;
    public  User(){
    }
    public User(String name, String email, String contact, String city, String age){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.city = city;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `setPhotoUri()` (then update user):

From the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users?hl=es):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
    .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
    .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
    .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
            }
        }
    });
```

You can also store the image in Firebase Storage and then save that download link in the Firebase database.